# Force vs2017 15.3 to use dotnet sdk 1.1.0 instead of 2.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have the following problem. After upgrading to vs2017 15.3 I get the following error

```
"Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Content' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultContentItems' property to 'false'".
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets
```

I am using a third party library abp framework so it is not possible to edit the csproj file as they come as dll.

How do I force visual studio to use C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.1.0\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add global.json for appropriate sdk in root of your repo. Make sure you only have one

E.g
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.4"
  }
}

See here https://andrewlock.net/the-net-core-2-0-preview-1-version-numbers-and-global-json/amp/

Comment: Thank you very much